# Use Insert Key to toggle insert/overwrite mode in Bash Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, gnome-terminal

After years of annoyance I finally setup Insert/Overwrite mode in Bash Terminal by creating this file:

```
$ cat ~/.inputrc

# ~/.inputrc - complements /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# April 15, 2019
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

$include /etc/inputrc

Control-o: overwrite-mode
```

See: [info rluserman](http://www.manpagez.com/info/rluserman/rluserman-6.2/rluserman_16.php#Commands-For-Text)

I could always recall previous command with the <kbd>⭡</kbd> (Up Arrow) key and reposition the cursor for editing. I was always annoyed having to erase characters and insert new ones rather than replacing.

Now I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to turn off Insert Mode and type over existing characters. Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> again to restore Insert Mode.

But how can I assign the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to toggle `overwrite-mode` on and off?

Comment: `"\e[2~": overwrite-mode` can you replace this line with your line `Control-o: overwrite-mode` and see as a quick test to possible duplicate link..

Comment: @PRATAP, Works great, thanks to both you and the OP, I've been wondering about this.  I did comment out the previous binding to the insert key `#"\e[2~": quoted-insert` (don't think I ever used it).